# select first dl element in css

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have this html:

```
<div id="gallery-1" class="gallery galleryid-39 gallery-columns-3 gallery-size-thumbnail gallery1">

<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<dl class="gallery-item"></dl>
<dl class="gallery-item"></dl>
<dl class="gallery-item"></dl>
<br style="clear: both"></br>
<dl class="gallery-item"></dl>
<dl class="gallery-item"></dl>
<br style="clear: both"></br>

</div>
```

and this css:

```
.gallery dl:first-child {
display: none;
}
```

and it`s not working, I do not know why

Comment: `.gallery dl:first-of-type` would be better.

Answer (score 3):

`dl:first-child` won't match the `<dl>` element since it is not the **first child** of its parent. (*Actually the first child of `.gallery` is a `<script>` element)*

In order to target the first `<dl>` element, you could use [`:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) pseudo class instead:

```css
.gallery > dl:first-of-type {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

script is the first child of div. so it cant get selected. if you want to access first dl then use dl:first-of-type

Here is fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/dlinx/3jd1mgr7/1/)

```
<div id="gallery-1" class="gallery galleryid-39 gallery-columns-3 gallery-size-thumbnail gallery1">

<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<dl class="gallery-item"></dl>
<dl class="gallery-item"></dl>
<dl class="gallery-item"></dl>
<br style="clear: both"></br>
<dl class="gallery-item"></dl>
<dl class="gallery-item"></dl>
<br style="clear: both"></br>

</div>



.gallery > dl:first-of-type {
display:none
}
```